# Larave can't detect correct Notification class

Tags: php, laravel

After creating a simple driver for `Laravel` notification as `SmsChannel` when i try to use `Laravel notification` i get this error:

```
TypeError
App\Channels\SmsChannel::send(): Argument #2 ($notification) 
must be of type Illuminate\Notifications\Notification, Modules\User\Notifications\SendVerifyCode given, 
called in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php on line 148
```

`SmsChannel` class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Channels;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SmsChannel
{
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        return $notification->toSms($notifiable);
    }
}
```

and `SendVerifyCode` notification class:

```php
<?php

namespace Modules\User\Notifications;

use App\Channels\SmsChannel;
use App\Models\ActivationCode;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class SendVerifyCode implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, InteractsWithQueue;

    private string $mobile_number;

    public function __construct(string $mobile_number)
    {
        $this->mobile_number = $mobile_number;
    }

    public function via(): array
    {
        return [SmsChannel::class];
    }

    public function toSms()
    {
        $code = ActivationCode::createCode($this->mobile_number);
    }

    public function toArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'mobile_number' => $this->mobile_number
        ];
    }
}
```

`composer-dumpautoload` command couldn't resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating custom notifications, you should extend Laravel's base notification class.

```php
<?php

namespace Modules\User\Notifications;

use App\Channels\SmsChannel;
use App\Models\ActivationCode;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class SendVerifyCode extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
```